# How to ignore missing role error on Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-galaxy

We have an ansible project using a lot of roles which are not included in the same git repository (I will refer to it as external roles). We use ansible-galaxy with a requirements.yml file to install these roles but we have to run it manually and frequently to get the last version of the roles.

I want to get rid of this manual task, so I created a playbook that will be called before the others via import_playbook in the site.yml. It's only purpose is running the ansible-galaxy command to ensure that the external roles are installed and in the last version available.

**Projet Structure :**

```
- project
  - roles
    - project_role1
    - project_role2
    - requirements.yml
  - playbook
    - 1_install_roles.yml
    - 2_mainplaybook.yml
  - site.yml

- external_roleA
  - tasks ...
```

**site.yml**

```
  - import_playbook: ./playbooks/install_roles.yml
  - import_playbook: ./playbooks/playbook1.yml
```

**1_install_roles.yml**

```
---
- hosts: localhost
    
  tasks:
    - name: Auto-Update ansible role
      command: ansible-galaxy install -r roles/requirements.yml -p roles --force
      delegate_to: localhost
      register: galaxy-output
      changed_when: '"was installed successfully" in galaxy-output.stdout'

    - name: Show ansible-galaxy output
      debug: msg="{{ galaxy-output.stdout }}"
```

**2_mainplaybook.yml**

```
---
  - name: mainplaybook
    hosts: all
    
    roles:
    - role: project_role1
    - role: external_roleA
    - role: project_role2
```

It works for updating the roles but fail when the roles are not installed yet on the local machine, I got the following error :

```
ERROR! the role 'external_roleA' was not found
```

Because at this time ansible is right, the role cannot be found but will be installed before reaching this particular step. So my question is how to ignore this error ? or how do I tell ansible not to check for roles before using them.

Comment: Use include_role in tasks which will evaluate only at time it is run but I'm not even sure that will work.

Comment: @zeitounator Had the same idea and the same worry. Charly will have to try this...

Comment: @Zeitounator Yes it works using incliude_role in tasks inside the playbook. Looks like Ansible only check roles listed under the roles keyword.

Comment: @CharlyRoch ansible checks roles at the time it needs to use them. Roles listed under `roles` play keyword are statically imported, so ansible checks them at start. You should get the same behavior if you use `import_role` in your tasks. `include_role` will do this dynamically at time the specific task is played. I was just unsure (and could not test on my phone last night....) if ansible was still constructing a list of available roles at start or not. You just confirmed it does this on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned by @Zeitounator a solution is to use **include_role** in tasks inside the playbook.

```
---
  - name: mainplaybook
    hosts: all
    
    tasks:
      - include_role: 
        name: external_roleA
```

When mixing Tasks and Roles in a playbook be aware that Ansible has a specific order of execution:

> When you use the roles option at the play level, Ansible treats the
> roles as static imports and processes them during playbook parsing.
> Ansible executes your playbook in this order:
>
> - Any pre_tasks defined in the play.
> - Any handlers triggered by pre_tasks.
> - Each role listed in roles:, in the order listed. Any role dependencies defined in the role’s meta/main.yml run first, subject to tag filtering and conditionals. See Using role dependencies for more details.
> - Any tasks defined in the play.
> - Any handlers triggered by the roles or tasks.
> - Any post_tasks defined in the play.
> - Any handlers triggered by post_tasks.